# .innerHTML += id, no duplicates

Tags: javascript, html

Here what I have so I have a long list of check-boxes and I want to display them in text if they are check I was thinking of using the code below, but the problem I'm having is if they check and uncheck a check-box it shows up multiple times any suggestion on how to fix this?

> .innerHTML += id;

If you need some more details here's a code dump of the relevant code:

### Javascript

```
function findTotal() {
    var items = new Array();
    var itemCount = document.getElementsByClassName("items");
    var total = 0;
    var id = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < itemCount.length; i++) {
        id = "c" + (i + 1);
        if (document.getElementById(id).checked) {
            total = total + parseInt(document.getElementById(id).value);
            document.getElementById(id).parentNode.classList.add("active");
            document.getElementById(id).parentNode.classList.remove("hover");
            document.getElementById('display').innerHTML += id;
        } else {
            document.getElementById(id).parentNode.classList.remove("active");
            document.getElementById(id).parentNode.classList.add("hover");
        }
    }
    console.log(total);
    document.getElementById('displayTotal').value = total;
}
```

### HTML

```
<label class="hover topping" for="c4">
  <input class="items" onclick="findTotal()" type="checkbox" name="topping" value="1.00" id="c4">BABYBEL</label>
```

Note: many more label classes

Comment: Dude. Simplify your code. You don't need to post 17 copies of the mostly same input element.

Comment: Actually it needs more rethinking. Many unnecessary DOM queries.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I agree, I am using javascript as a challenge for my self here and Its required for this project for other reasons.

Comment: Stick `document.getElementById(id)` in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Previous answer should do it. Here your code (see comment "clear container"
Additionally I have simplified your code a bit. Readability greatly increased.
Maybe you should switch to jQuery in general, much simpler for your example.

```
var displayElement = document.getElementById('display'),
    displayTotalElement = document.getElementById('displayTotal');

function findTotal() {
    var items = [],
    itemCount = document.getElementsByClassName("items"),
    total = 0,
    id = '';

    // clear container
    displayElement.innerHTML = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < itemCount.length; i++) {
        id = "c" + (i + 1);
        var element = document.getElementById(id),
            elementsParent = element.parentNode;
        if (element.checked) {
            total = total + parseInt(element.value, 10);
            elementsParent.classList.add("active");
            elementsParent.classList.remove("hover");
            displayElement.innerHTML += id;
        } else {
            elementsParent.classList.remove("active");
            elementsParent.classList.add("hover");
        }
    }
    console.log(total);
    displayTotalElement.value = total;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reset the text before the loop:

```
document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = '';
```

At the moment you're just always adding to whatever's already there…

Comment: Yes, sorry for not making this clear I need a bit of a break. I was looking to list each id with no duplicates.

Comment: @Josh: Why are there duplicate checkboxes?

Comment: They arnt duplicate checkboxs their id tag changes, c4 c5 c6 etc and the text inside

Comment: I got a comment =  Dude. Simplify your code. You don't need to post 17 copies of the mostly same input element. – evolutionxbox

Comment: @Josh: That has nothing to do with me